# NuxtJS child dynamic pages not being navigated to/rendering with nuxt-link

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-link

If my file structure is:

```
- pages
-- catrules.vue
-- catrules/
---- _id.vue
```

The child page does not render (but the url updates and the page stays on the parent):
`<nuxt-link :to="'/catrules/' + catrule.slug">{{ catrule.ruleid }}</nuxt-link>`

If I change the name of the the directory `catrules` to `catrule`, then everything works as expected:

```
- pages
-- catrules.vue
-- catrule/
---- _id.vue
```

`<nuxt-link :to="'/catrule/' + catrule.slug">{{ catrule.ruleid }}</nuxt-link>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use this structure:

```
- pages
-- catrules/
---- _id.vue
---- index.vue
```

So just rename your `pages/catrules.vue` as `pages/catrules/index.vue`

see https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#nested-routes